# Outlook 2011 Keychain entry rewritten - prompting for password after 10.10.5 update - keychain issue?

Tags: macos, ms-office, keychain

After applying the Yosemite 10.10.5 update and Security Update 2015-004 (1.0), my installation of Outlook 2011 prompts me for a password every time I check for mail. I have tried repairing Keychain Access a few times (on Verify, it says there is never a problem) and deleting/recreating the keychain login entries for Outlook, but I continue to be prompted to reenter my credentials:

[image: Prompt from Outlook after forgetting password]

[image: Adding keychain entry]

After entering the credentials, I show as connected and can send/receive all my mail. There is also a login entry displayed in Keychain Access. But the prompt still appears on every send/receive.

I have seen [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192221/exchange-2011-keeps-asking-for-password) of adding an additional backslash to the beginning of the domain (i.e. `\domain\user` instead of `domain\user` ) but doing so returns a bad user/pass error.

The 10.10.5 update description says it "improves compatibility with certain email servers when using Mail" - thinking this might be a clue?

My coworker's mac (which hasn't been updated) does not have this issue, and my iPhone and Win7/Outlook 2007 installs are receiving mail from the same account with no login problems. Mail server settings have not changed (I manage it).

**EDIT**

Reviewing the keychain entry after getting the wrong credentials prompts, I see that the username has been changed from `domain\username` to `username@example.com` but the prompt keeps coming up suggesting `domain\username`. (Attempting `username@example.com` fails with bad user/pass error.) The change to the keychain entry occurs when relaunching Outlook or after a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange "autodiscover" settings changes the server URL to the WSDL resource.

So, mail.domain.com becomes: mail.domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx everytime you check for mail.

To fix this, you have to tell Outlook to stop asking for autodiscover settings 
using AppleScript editor:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
set background autodiscover of exchange account "NameOfAccount" to false
end tell
```

*credit: http://www.officeformachelp.com/2011/01/exchange-autodiscover-workaround-for-advanced-settings/*

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I actually did play around with turning on/off autodiscover but I had a few things wrong (which I will edit in my original post) - my coworker with the same setup did in fact have the same problem with her installation. The connection string changes were a red herring. The problem had to do with a public mail folder in Exchange that had some permissions issues. Known issue from M$ and they're apparently working on a patch. Only affects Exchange 2013 installs that were migrations from 2010.

Comment: cool, glad you found a solution :)